# In a cakephp 3 app, how do I build a query that finds all from a Table that does NOT contain it's associated table?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is there a simple way to get the inverse of the `contain` method of the querybuilder?

I'm using belongsToMany associations with a join table to associate the two Models.

EmailsTable `$this->belongsToMany('Issues');`

IssuesTable `$this->belongsToMany('Emails');`

so I can't just do something like:

```
$unparsed_emails = $this->Emails->find('all')->where(['issue_id is null']);
```

It seems like the inverse of the following would provide Emails that do NOT have associated Issues yet:

```
$unparsed_emails = $this->Emails->find->contain(['Issues']);  //need inverse of this
```

I think I must be missing something from the cakephp 3 ORM/Querybuilder documentation, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not yet that much into the query builder, so I'm not sure whether there are simpler methods, but a left join should do it.

```php
$this->Emails
    ->find('all')
    ->leftJoin('emails_issues', 'emails_issues.email_id = Emails.id')
    ->where('emails_issues.id IS NULL');
```

This should translate into a query like

```sql
SELECT
    Emails.id AS `Emails__id`, ...
FROM
    emails AS Emails
LEFT JOIN
    emails_issues emails_issues ON emails_issues.email_id = Emails.id
WHERE
    emails_issues.id IS NULL
```

which would select all emails that don't have any issues assigned.

Comment: Thanks @ndm. I was wondering if I would need to do a join just like that.  I ended up setting a boolean column `parsed` that I set true, then check for, but I think I prefer your solution

Comment: Just a heads up, I believe joins have to be passed a keyed array like so: 
`->join([
  'table' => 'comments',
  'alias' => 'c',
  'type' => 'LEFT',
  'conditions' => 'c.article_id = articles.id',
]);`

Comment: @MikeT They don't necessarily have to, [**`leftJoin()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_leftJoin), [**`rightJoin()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_rightJoin) and [**`innerJoin()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_innerJoin) are shorthand helpers for building it "manually" with [**`join()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_join).